# SvgUri import failed. React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

I'm trying to use a .svg image but when I render it in my component I get the following error:

> Attempted import error: 'react-native-svg-uri' does not contain a
> default export (imported as 'SvgUri').

My code:

```
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';

const screenBg=require('../../src/assets /logo.svg');

<View style = {stylesLoginScreen.logoContainer}>
              <SvgUri source = {screenBg}
                             width = '100'
                             height = '100'>
              </SvgUri>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a named export. Use it as

`import { SvgUri } from 'react-native-svg';`